# Replace DEB.SURY.ORG PHP with original

Tags: apt, php, repository

I added Ondřej Surý's repository which was a great help at the time.
Now I have issues installing cURL and I think returning to "original" PHP would solve the problem.

Currently all my PHP packages are from DEB.SURY.ORG repository.

```
ii  php5                              5.5.12+dfsg-2+deb.sur all
ii  php5-cli                          5.5.12+dfsg-2+deb.sur amd64
ii  php5-common                       5.5.12+dfsg-2+deb.sur amd64
ii  php5-gd                           5.5.12+dfsg-2+deb.sur amd64
ii  php5-imagick                      3.1.2-1+debphp.org~pr amd64
ii  php5-json                         1.3.4-3+deb.sury.org~ amd64
rc  php5-mcrypt                       5.5.8+dfsg-3+sury.org amd64
ii  php5-mysql                        5.5.12+dfsg-2+deb.sur amd64
```

I have already removed the Ondřej's .list file.

How can I switch back to the original php packages causing minimal disruptions for my users?

Comment: Add back the PPA, the use `ppa-purge`.

Comment: @Oli Pretty sure someone has already said it, so I am searching for the original to flag as dupe. If not I'll post as answer.

Comment: @muru, this solved my problem and I am very grateful. Please post it as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Having problems installing wine32 on Ubuntu 20.04 ? This repo may be your enemy : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301883/wine-wine32-requires-dependencies-that-wont-be-installed-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: In this case, you should have been able to install "php-curl" - if "php --version" returned the correct version that you wanted it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrading packages is a very difficult problem. You should use [`ppa-purge`](https://askubuntu.com/a/313/158442) for this. But `ppa-purge` requires that the PPA be still added, so you will have to add back the PPA, and then use it.

Comment: For Ubuntu, the common repo is `ppa:ondrej/php` to (re)add this: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` and then to purge this: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php` it's even listed on https://deb.sury.org/ as "Ubuntu PPA", don't ask me why isn't it called deb.sury.org ...........

Comment: Also you may encouter problem php7.3 will no longer be available, but php7.4 will :)

Comment: To purge the packages themselves afterwards refer to https://askubuntu.com/a/1302278/277898